# Creating package body

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a package and there everything is ok. I think the package is well made.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE utl_zadaci AS
  2  PROCEDURE insertZadatak (
  3     p_naziv varchar2,
  4     p_kategorija varchar2,
  5     p_opis varchar2,
  6     p_komanda varchar2
  7  );
  8  
  9  PROCEDURE deleteZadatak (
 10         p_id number
 11    );
 12  
 13   PROCEDURE displayZadatak (
 14         p_id number,
 15     p_naziv varchar2,
 16         p_kategorija varchar2,
 17     p_opis varchar2,
 18     p_komanda varchar2
 19    );
 20  
 21  PROCEDURE modifyZadatak (
 22     p_id number,
 23     p_naziv varchar2,
 24     p_kategorija varchar2,
 25     p_opis varchar2,
 26     p_komanda varchar2
 27   );
 28  END utl_zadaci;
 29  /

 Package created.
```

The problem arises when I create the body of the package.

There is an error that I can not find here

In this I'm a beginner, I create a package for the first time. I need to write more for update and select.

If you know, I would be very grateful to help you here too: D

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY utl_zadaci AS
 2  PROCEDURE insertZadatak(
 3  p_naziv VARCHAR2,
 4  p_kategorija VARCHAR2,
 5  p_opis VARCHAR2,
 6  p_komanda VARCHAR2)
 7  IS
 8  BEGIN
 9  INSERT INTO zadaci(id, naziv, kategorija, opis, komanda)
 10  VALUES(SEQ_ZADACI_ID.NEXTVAL, p_naziv, p_kategorija, p_opis, p_komanda);
 11  COMMIT;
 12  EXCEPTION
 13   WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14      ROLLBACK;
 15      RAISE;
 16  END;
 17  
 18  PROCEDURE deleteZadatak(
 19  p_id NUMBER)
 20  IS
 21  BEGIN
 22  DELETE FROM zadaci
 23  WHERE id = p_id;
 24  COMMIT;
 25  EXCEPTION
 26   WHEN OTHERS THEN
 27      ROLLBACK;
 28      RAISE;
 29  END;
 30  END utl_zadaci;
 31  /
```

> Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

Comment: if you're using SQLPlus, type `SHOW ERRORS` to display the error messages

Comment: You seriously need to be able to list compilation errors if you are going to be working with PL/SQL, just like any other language. There are tools such as Oracle SQL Developer that will do it for you automatically.

Comment: What is the point of those `when others` exceptions? If all a procedure does is attempt to insert one row, and it doesn't work for any reason, what is there to roll back, apart from any earlier changes you made in your session before you had the misfortune to call the procedure?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to write more for update and select.

This is the issue. The package expects all the procedures in the specification to also be in the body; they aren't so there is an exception.

To list the exceptions you can run:

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

or you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

So for your code:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03af65/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE zadaci(
  id VARCHAR2(20),
  naziv VARCHAR2(20),
  kategorija VARCHAR2(20),
  opis VARCHAR2(20),
  komanda VARCHAR2(20)
)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ZADACI_ID
/

/* Your code */
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03af65/1/0)**:

```
|       NAME |         TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION |                                                                                                                            TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
|------------|--------------|----------|------|----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|----------------|
| UTL_ZADACI | PACKAGE BODY |        1 |   11 |       13 | PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'DISPLAYZADATAK' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body |     ERROR |            323 |
| UTL_ZADACI | PACKAGE BODY |        2 |   18 |       13 |  PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'MODIFYZADATAK' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body |     ERROR |            323 |
```

*As an aside - do not use `COMMIT` in procedures. If you do then you cannot use multiple procedures in a transaction and rollback the entire transaction if later procedures raise an error as the earlier procedures will already have been committed. Instead issue the `COMMIT` statement in the block that calls the procedure(s).*

Comment: Now I've fixed it, look

Comment: @Petar Do not answer your question by editing the question to fix the errors - that invalidates all the existing answers. If you have fixed the issue in the question and there are now new errors then please do due diligence and search for solutions to those errors and if you cannot find any solutions then post a new question rather than overwriting the existing one.

Comment: @Petar If you are now getting PLS-00428 errors then [searching for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20213209/1509264) should bring you a solution (if the text of the error message is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact error here is what I can infer from the code you posted.
You have 4 procedures in your spec but only two in the body. 
You need to define the `displayZadatak` and `modifyZadatak` procedures.

**EDIT:** After the original question was edited here are the issues seen.

The `insertZadatak` procedure takes 4 arguments but in the body only 3 are present.

In the `displayZadatak` procedure, Select needs to be clubbed with an INTO in PLSQL to store the selected values. It can be a single variable, rowtype or collection.

Comment: Now I've fixed it, look

Answer (score 0):

There is only one small error here in the select procedure

```
 SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY utl_zadaci AS 

  2  PROCEDURE insertZadatak(
  3     p_naziv VARCHAR2,
  4     p_kategorija VARCHAR2,
  5     p_opis VARCHAR2,
  6     p_komanda VARCHAR2)
  7  IS
  8  BEGIN
  9     INSERT INTO zadaci(id, naziv, kategorija, opis, komanda)
 10     VALUES(SEQ_ZADACI_ID.NEXTVAL, p_naziv, p_kategorija, p_opis, p_komanda);
 11  COMMIT;
 12  EXCEPTION
 13    WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14       ROLLBACK;
 15       RAISE;
 16  END;
 17  PROCEDURE deleteZadatak(
 18    p_id NUMBER)
 19  IS
 20  BEGIN
 21     DELETE FROM zadaci
 22     WHERE id = p_id;
 23   COMMIT;
 24  EXCEPTION
 25     WHEN OTHERS THEN
 26       ROLLBACK;
 27      RAISE;
 28  END;
 29  PROCEDURE modifyZadatak(
 30     p_id NUMBER,
 31     p_naziv VARCHAR2,
 32     p_kategorija VARCHAR2,
 33     p_opis VARCHAR2,
 34     p_komanda VARCHAR2)
 35  IS
 36  BEGIN
 37     UPDATE zadaci SET naziv = p_naziv, kategorija = p_kategorija, opis = p_opis,
 38     komanda = p_komanda WHERE id = p_id;
 39   COMMIT;
 40    EXCEPTION
 41    WHEN OTHERS THEN
 42       ROLLBACK;
 43       RAISE;
 44   END;
 45   PROCEDURE displayZadatak(p_id NUMBER,
 46   p_naziv VARCHAR2,
 47   p_kategorija VARCHAR2,
 48   p_opis VARCHAR2,
 49   p_komanda VARCHAR2)
 50   IS
 51   BEGIN
 52   SELECT naziv, kategorija, opis, komanda
 53  INTO p_naziv, p_kategorija, p_opis, p_komanda
 54  FROM zadaci WHERE id = p_id;
 55  COMMIT;
 56  EXCEPTION
 57  WHEN OTHERS THEN
 58     ROLLBACK;
 59     RAISE;
 60  END;
 61  END utl_zadaci;
 62  /
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create the package without procedures
2. create the package body
3. put the procedures on the package and then in the package body.

Comment: A slightly different process that has server me well. 1. Create and compile the package spec with procedures/ functions.  2. Change header "package' to 'package body' 3. Insert code "begin null; end;" or "begin return null; end;" to each procedure/function. 4. Compile body. This ensures the requirement that procedure/function declarations in body exactly matches the spec. Now go back and write specific code for each procedure/function.